# Can't upload files to Google Drive from ES File Explorer

Tags: google-drive, es-file-explorer, uploads

I opened the Google Drive app and tried to upload files using ES File Explorer, but it said upload fails. It gave two options, upload in the normal Android way, and file way (if above fails). I tried both, but it failed.

Some of the files having the same types did upload, but some exact same PDF didn't.

The system and apps are up to date.

Device - POCO X3 PRO(india)
Android version 11
MIUI - 12.0.5(Global)

Comment: Could you mention the device model and the Android version?

Comment: I don't know how to ping here, xd

Comment: Use @ followed by user's name to ping them. Example: @Natsu21

Comment: Oh i don't whom to ping, i thought people will view this questions without any mentioning, any suggestions? @firelord